# Passing data to another view controller in swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

How do I send coredata values when selecting a row in table view to another view controller using SHOW SEGUE in swift 3?

This is my code in objective c using Present Modally Segue and I want the equivalent of that code in swift 3 using Show Segue because I'm using a navigation controller.  I've been working on this for a couple hours but as of now, I still haven't been able to do it.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateDevice"])
{

        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        detailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.account = selectedDevice;

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very short on details and therefore is currently falls into the categories of being **too broad** and/or **unclear of what you are asking** which are both cases for it to be closed. Are you able to therefore edit your question and explain your problem further? For example, give some context on what you are trying to actually achieve that results in you having to do what you have asked in the question. There's a good article in the Help Centre which provides some guidance on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with more details. You've mentioned that you attempted to do some of the conversion yourself. If so, adding your attempt so far would also help. Also note that you don't need to put block quotes character ('>') around your question text unless you are actually quoting another source.